Why is Coherence Factor Not Always 1 (Signal Processing)
I was wondering why the Coherence Factor of 2 signals is not always 1. I understand that the coherence factor is defined as $$\frac{|G_{xy}(f)|^2}{G_{xx}(f)G_{yy}(f)},$$ where $G_{xy}(f)$ is the cross spectral density that is defined as $$X^*(f)Y(f)$$ (for 2 signals $x(t)$, $y(t)$ with Fourier Transforms $X(t)$, $Y(t)$ and conjugation denoted by a $*$) and $G_xx(f)$ is the auto-spectral density of signal $x(t)$ (similarly for $y(t)$) defined as $|X(f)|^2.$ If you plug these 2 equations into the definition of the coherence factor, you clearly get 1. From what I have read, the Coherence factor ranges from 0 to 1, and the Coherence becomes less than 1 when noise is introduced into the system, or in other words, $y(t)$ is not completely dependent on $x(t)$, but I don't understand how this is the case, as the reasoning above does not consider whether x and y have noise. I also understand the alternate definitions of cross-spectral density and auto-spectral density using the Fourier transform of the cross-correlation/autocorrelation functions respectively, but since these are mathematically equivalent to the above definitions, I want to understand why we simply cannot just plug in the formulas and get that the Coherence is always 1. Please explain this to me with assuming as little background in signal processing/spectral analysis as possible.
Thank you all so much for your help! It is much appreciated.

$X=[0,1,0,1],Y=[1,0,1,0]$
